# How do I make a button in a ButtonBar selected by default?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have a Spark ButtonBar and I got it hooked up correctly with a ViewStack. Currently, when I run the application (AIR), the first button in the ButtonBar is selected by default. How can I make the second button selected by default?

```
<mx:ViewStack id="viewStack">
    <s:NavigatorContent id="Page 1">
        <!-- Other stuff in here -->
    </s:NavigatorContent>
    <s:NavigatorContent id="Page 2">
        <!-- Other stuff in here -->
    </s:NavigatorContent>
</mx:ViewStack>

<s:ButtonBar dataProvider="{viewStack}" selectedIndex="1"></s:ButtonBar>
```

Comment: Haven't used it before, but the button bar doesn have a selectedIndex? It had it if i remember well in framework 3.0 with flex builder 3

Comment: I tried that, but no the first button in the ButtonBar remains selected regardless of the value I put in for the selected index. Weird!

Comment: hehe, try to put it after you assign the data provider for it,  or maybe in the creationcomplete event, just to avoid technologies problems.. have you tried to click a button and change the selectedIndex in that moment like myButtonBar.selectedIndex = 1; if it works.. is that the selectedIndex is being dispatched BEfore you data provider is assigned to.. you need to assign it after, dont knwo if it has the dataproviderChanged event.. or something like that

Answer (score 1):

I Did this and it worked good. Are you sure the selectedIndex is not working?

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:ButtonBar 
        selectedIndex="2" width="400" height="300">
        <s:dataProvider>
            <s:ArrayCollection>
                <fx:String>1</fx:String>
                <fx:String>2</fx:String>
                <fx:String>3</fx:String>
            </s:ArrayCollection>
        </s:dataProvider>

    </s:ButtonBar>

</s:Application>
```

**Edit:**

This helps you?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600" creationComplete="init()">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            import mx.events.CollectionEvent;
            [Bindable]
            private var dataSource:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

            private function init():void
            {

                dataSource = new ArrayCollection(new Array("1","2","3"));
                dataSource.addEventListener(CollectionEvent.COLLECTION_CHANGE, collectionEventChange);
                dataSource.dispatchEvent(new CollectionEvent(CollectionEvent.COLLECTION_CHANGE));

            }

            private function collectionEventChange(event:CollectionEvent):void
            {
                this.btnBar.selectedIndex = 2;
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:ButtonBar  id="btnBar" dataProvider="{dataSource}"
         width="400" height="300" >

    </s:ButtonBar>

</s:Application>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is what I did:
`<s:ButtonBar left="0" bottom="0" selectedIndex="1" dataProvider="{dataSource}"/>`
And I also tried:
`<s:ButtonBar left="0" bottom="0" dataProvider="{dataSource} selectedIndex="1" "/>` but the `selectedIndex` still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: when do you asign the datasource?

Comment: I'm using a `<mx:ViewStack>` with `<s:NavigatorContent>` inside it (I updated my question to reflect this.) Thanks again for helping!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the selected index *after* the component has been initialized and *after* the button bar has been populated.  The buttonbar only creates the buttons when it detects a change in it's dataprovider (by attaching a changewatcher to it once it has been bound).

That's why Mr.'s revised answer has the stuff with the setting the selected index inside a CollectionEvent listener.

The more robust solution is to subclass buttonbar and tweak it, adding a defaultSelectedIndex member, or create a mixin that can add this functionality to any subclass of listbase. The defaultSelectedIndex would set the selected index to the specified value when its dataprovider changes.